# How can I programmatically change the system's status?

Tags: system-status

I have a console controller action that needs to change the site's status under certain conditions. I have not been able to find any documentation or even questions out there about how to do this. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two existing console commands you can use, `./craft on` and `./craft off` ([on](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/console-commands.html#on) and [off](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/console-commands.html#off)).

If you want/need to implement your own, take a look at [the commit](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/commit/e919ea1a5bd36a9165c6539488c74f263090ded4).

Comment: I didn't even think to look at Craft's own console commands :facepalm: thanks!! And also thank you for posting the link to that commit! :)